# How to include a humans.txt file in my Symfony app?

Tags: symfony1

I made a humans.txt file and put it in my /web directory, but I'm still getting a 404. How do I get it to show up?

Answer (score 2):

If /web is your webroot, and you're visiting `yourdomain/humans.txt` it should show up without anything special to do. Make sure the filename is correct, and the webserver has read access to the file.